# Downloading OpenStreetMap data by osmosis?

Tags: osmosis

I need to download a geographic data and unzip the download file using osmosis command. I tried this:

```
osmosis --rx test.osm --bb top=48.78 left=6.02 bottom=48.59 right=6.38
```

but this command filters OSM files by BBox and it does not import the data from the OSM server.

Answer (score 2):

Osmosis is not a download tool.

You need to download data from the Server with the export function of the website, but this is limited in size due to limited server resources.

It is encouraged to use the Overpass API instead, or take a Geofabrik extract of the area of your interest.

See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data for details on downloading, and http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.45 on the osmosis syntax.